# Certain Tkinter options not available when in IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-idle

I am trying to create a button that when the widget is active in changes color (I am using python-idle3).

I tried importing tkinter as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
```

My button creation codes are as follows but does not work when I included the `activebackground` option

```
start_button=Button(window_frame,text="START",width=70,height=2).grid(row=8,column=0,stick="E",activebackground="black")
```

Error message when using `activebackground`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/root/Desktop/GUi #1.py",
line 37, in <module>
   Button_expirement()   File "/root/Desktop/GUi #1.py", line 26, in Button_expirement
   start_button=Button(window_frame,text="START",width=70,height=2).grid(row=8,column=0,stick="E",activebackground="black")
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1914, in
grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
**_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-activebackground": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky**
```

I noticed that some other widget features are also limited. Any solution to this?

Comment: As far as I know, your title is untrue when running Idle in the normal mode, without passing the -n option on startup. TclErrors come from tcl/tk and should be correct when properly understood. @twasbrillig beat me to the correct solution to your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activebackground` isn't part of the function call to `grid`. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

But it **is** in the function call to `Button`. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

So perhaps you meant to write this?

```
start_button=Button(window_frame,text="START",width=70,height=2,activebackground="black").grid(row=8,column=0,stick="E")
```

...or if you meant to set the background to black, you can set it in the `Tk` variable (see 
[Python Tkinter how to color a window using grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317211/python-tkinter-how-to-color-a-window-using-grid)).

```
root = Tk()           
root.configure(bg='black')
```

Comment: Oops i put it in the wrong place and was wondering what could have been the issue!..i am still getting acquainted with tkinter..thank you

Comment: Sure thing. If the answer was helpful, please click the green checkmark next to it, thanks.